# Not able to load my SP 2013 Sever in IE 10

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, internet-explorer

My SharePoint 2013 Server is not loading in IE 10 in my development environment. It keeps on prompting user credentials for three times and eventually ends up in a white screen.

[image]

Everything works fine in Firefox. Some of the features of SharePoint is available only in IE so I can explore them.

[image]

Any one had similar issues? How did you fix it?

Some information about my Development Box Environment:

Virtual Machine: Oracle Virtual Box
 Server: Windows 2012 
 SharePoint: 2013 
 Browser: IE 10

[image]

Comment: Loopback check? - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861

Comment: Well, you are using a different username in IE, apadmin instead of spadmin..

Comment: Great observation Robert and that served my purpose.